# HTML Links are not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am currently creating a website, and for some reason a simple task linking to another web page is not working. When I try and link something I get

> This webpage is not found. No webpage was found for the web address: C:\me\me\me etc etc".

All I am trying to do is link a work to another page on my web page. Here is my code:

```
<a href="C:\\users\rob\website\page.html">page link</a>
```

I have also just tried linking google and amazon and get the same results.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="file://C:\users\rob\website\page.html"> page link </a>
```

Also, 
You **cannot** load local resources using `file://` if the page is hosted on a **webserver**. That would be a security issue and is hence, forbidden.

Your script console will, in that case also contain:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/users/rob/website/page.html
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the quote on the link. Try `<a href="URL goes here" > page link </a>`

For instance, `<a href="http://www.google.com/" > Google </a>`

Also, remember that "C:..." is not a web address, if you want to test locally, try using the `file://` prefix.

For instance, `<a href="file://C:\me\me\me\page.html" > My Page</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the second "

try this:

```
<a href="C:\users\rob\website\page.html"> page link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <a href="file:///C|\users\rob\website\page.html" > page link < /a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href = "../foldername/filename" > </a>`

../ Defines the root. when you use this style it searches for the file location from the root.